# Caused by: com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When launching an activity my app crashes at getEncryptedSharedPrefs:

```
    if(getEncryptedSharedPrefs().getString("pinSettingsLogin", "")!!.isEmpty()){
        getEncryptedSharedPrefs().edit()
            .putString("pinSettingsLogin" , "0000")
            .apply()
    }
```

With this error:

```
Caused by: com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

Weird thing is, this if statement works on Android 10 and 11 but not on Android 12. This if statement is here because in the 'if' below I check if the pinSettingsLogin = 0000 so that It goes to a new activity by it self.

```
    if(getEncryptedSharedPrefs().getString("pinSettingsLogin", "").equals("0000")){
        val i = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug from `EncryptedSharedPreferences`, the issue happens on the initialization of the `EncryptedSharedPreferences`.

Check it out [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164901843)

Comment: It looks like this may now be fixed in .NET 7: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/15650

Comment: can somebody share the answer here what i need to change in the code to fix this issue. Clearing cache is not a solution i cannot tell to the users that if it's crashing kindly clear the cache.

Comment: This error is occurring for years and it hasn't been fixed yet. I think it will never be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried clearing the app's cache?

This might fix the problem!

Comment: Yes, this fixed my problem. I tried this 3 times before, with no result but I guess now it works.

Comment: I got an app update. After that only, this solution works. Maybe works after a restart.

Comment: Can someone please explain what is causing this crash and how to fix it in the code, we can not expect that user will do clear data by himself he will just curse the app and leave

Comment: Does clearing the cache programmatically fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
 implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha04"
```

Initialize sharedpreference like given in documentation:

```
 val keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKey.Builder(activity)
.setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
.build()

        val sharedPref : SharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences
.create(activity,"secret_shared_prefs", keyGenParameterSpec, EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM)
```